# Different way to show the image from the device, instead of resources using BitmapFactory

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a small project, but yet different. So I found out that the bitmap works when the image is implemented from Android Studio and include it as resources(example: **BitmapFactory.decodeResources(resources, R.drawable.image.jpg)**) in order for the watermark to work, however I am struggling with something similar, but selecting a certain image from the android device, using by code of course, but later one probably gonna be questions once the gallery is selected to automatically place the watermark, but like I said that's a different question for another time. My question is there any possible way, when I press the watermark button, to automatically locate and place the image from the Android device on to the imageview, after that to place the text watermark ?
Also on the console log, I'm receiving this message: ***E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.cameraxapp/files (Is a directory)***

If any of you know the issue that I am having, please let me know and examples, will also be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

ActivityGallery.xml(It can be even in MainActivity.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8A8A8A"
    android:backgroundTint="#8A8A8A"
    tools:context=".ActivityGallery">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/watermarkSetBtn"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
        android:text="@string/watermark"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/saveButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/pickPhotoButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="670dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

GalleryActivity.kt

1. The main function for the watermark as Bitmap

```
private fun addWatermark(bitmap: Bitmap, watermarkText: String, options: WatermarkOptions = WatermarkOptions()): Bitmap {
        val result = bitmap.copy(bitmap.config, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(result)
        val paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or DITHER_FLAG)
        paint.textAlign = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> Paint.Align.LEFT
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }
        val textSize = result.width * options.textSizeToWidthRatio
        paint.textSize = textSize
        paint.color = options.textColor
        if (options.shadowColor != null) {
            paint.setShadowLayer(textSize / 2, 0f, 0f, options.shadowColor)
        }
        if (options.typeface != null) {
            paint.typeface = options.typeface
        }
        val padding = result.width * options.paddingToWidthRatio
        val coordinates = calculateCoordinates(watermarkText, paint, options, canvas.width, canvas.height, padding)
        canvas.drawText(watermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, paint)
        return result
    }

    private fun calculateCoordinates(watermarkText: String, paint: Paint, options: WatermarkOptions, width: Int, height: Int, padding: Float): PointF {
        val x = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> {
                    padding
                }
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                    width - padding
                }
        }

        val y = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                    height - padding
                }
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                Corner.TOP_RIGHT -> {
                val bounds = Rect()
                paint.getTextBounds(watermarkText, 0, watermarkText.length, bounds)
                val textHeight = bounds.height()
                textHeight + padding
                }
        }
        return PointF(x, y)
    }

    enum class Corner {
        TOP_LEFT,
        TOP_RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_LEFT,
        BOTTOM_RIGHT
    }

    data class WatermarkOptions(
            val corner: Corner = Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
            val textSizeToWidthRatio: Float = 0.04f,
            val paddingToWidthRatio: Float = 0.03f,
            @ColorInt val textColor: Int = Color.WHITE,
            @ColorInt val shadowColor: Int? = Color.BLACK,
            val typeface: Typeface? = null
    )

    companion object {
        //private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy.MM.dd-HH"
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
    }
```

2. Placing it on *onCreate* method

```
private lateinit var mImageView: ImageView
private lateinit var mWatermarkSet: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery)

        //Views
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto)
        mWatermarkSet = findViewById(R.id.watermarkSetBtn)

        mWatermarkSet.setOnClickListener {
            if (filesDir.isDirectory) {
                val internalStorage = filesDir.absolutePath
                val pathName = "$internalStorage"
                //resources, R.drawable.gefvqkbbslamdpkxf1zv_bigstock_aerial_view_of_blue_lakes_and__227291596
                val originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName)?.let { it ->
                    addWatermark(
                            it,
                            "@Test",
                            WatermarkOptions(
                                    Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
                                    textSizeToWidthRatio = 0.03f,
                                    paddingToWidthRatio = 0.03f,
                                    Color.GREEN,
                                    Color.BLACK,
                                    typeface = null
                            )
                    )
                }
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.cameraxapp/files (Is a directory)` Well the error looks clear to me. You try to decode a directory. Where you should try to decode an image file.

Comment: @blackapps I understand that, however I would like to guide it a different root directory, such as this:
*Internal Storage/Android/media/com.example.cameraxapp/CameraXApp/(spesific image).jpg*

Comment: `to guide it` ?? What do you mean? Load an image file from a different directory? You are now trying to load from `val internalStorage = filesDir.absolutePath`. So you should change the directory to external files dir.

Comment: And after that `val pathName = "$internalStorage/(spesific image).jpg"` Otherwise you would still try to decode a directory instead of the wanted file.

Comment: @blackapps I can tell that you're confused of what I am asking, my apologies. So I changed the coding as you said it from filesDir to getExternalFilesDir("CameraXApp"), the string on the inside is the name of the folder after the com.example.cameraxapp. Here is the result: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cameraxapp/files/CameraXApp/2021.02.26-16:56.jpg (No such file or directory). I'm sorry once again if that makes you frustrated, I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: Well.. if that file is not there.. if the file does not exist... then the message is ok. Did you use File(pathName).exists() to check if the file exists?

Comment: @blackapps No I haven't, where should I put the code that you suggested ?

Comment: Just before you try to decode that file as the decoding statement throws that exception is not it.

Comment: @blackapps Ok, I have found my issue and yes I was blind the whole time and I have to apologize for my mistake, what I realized is that when I take a photo, it saves on this directory "```/storage/emulated/0/Android/*media*/com.example.cameraxapp/files/CameraXApp/2021.02.26-16:56.jpg```". So what I did is to copy it manually to this directory "```/storage/emulated/0/Android/*data*/com.example.cameraxapp/files/CameraXApp/2021.02.26-16:56.jpg```". Once I press the button for the watermark it did showed up. So I have to think of other ways to make it detect by itself. Once again I apologies.